# Replacing urls for rewriting in Web.Debug.confing for multiple deployments

Tags: asp.net, azure-pipelines

Is there any way that I can replace the Redirect urls during release?  We have two different testing environments with different URLs.  We used to have Web.testing1.config and Web.testing2.config, but we want to start just being able to release Web.debug.config to both.  The problem is, though, they have two different urls, and thus these rewrite rules aren't going to work.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.example\.com$" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```